# Inserting image into post with different image size

Tags: images

I have a custom WordPress theme that I have made myself.

When I insert an image into a post I only get the option to add the full size image (see below screenshot):
[image]

In `Settings > Media` I have a number of different sizes defined. How come these options done appear when I'm inserting an image?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have look at add_image_size and add to your theme's functions.php file:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

Answer (score 0):

Just like **gurudeb** said but remember that you will have to either replicate thumbnails or re upload the images so that the thumbnails in your defined size can be created